# HTML conditionnal List

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, html, list

I have a Data Extension with 3 variables/columns.
In my email, i want to display the content of these 3 columns as follow :

Your products :

○ %%ID_Product_A%%

○ %%ID_Product_B%%

○ %%ID_Product_C%%

My customer Mr. Toto only bought the product A and the product C, so I want the display as follow :

Your products :

○ %%ID_Product_A%%

○ %%ID_Product_C%%

What I tried :

```
  <li style="line-height:200%"><b><span style="font-size:16px;">Your products: </span></b><ul>
   <li>
    <span style="font-size:16px;">%%ID_Product_A%% </span></li><li>
    <span style="font-size:16px;">%%ID_Product_B%% </span></li><li>
    <span style="font-size:16px;">%%ID_Product_C%% </span></li></ul></li>
```

The fact is that with this code, I made a preview and for my customer Mr Toto, I have the display as follow :

Your products :

○ %%ID_Product_A%%

○

○ %%ID_Product_C%%

=> It creates a space even if the customer did not have the product B.
Whereas I want :

Your products :

○ %%ID_Product_A%%

○ %%ID_Product_C%%

Does someone know how to adapt my code ?

Comment: You should check for whether the fields are empty, and only show the LI if they are not empty: https://ampscript.guide/empty/

Comment: thank you Lukas it worked ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Lukas, you can use if else condition to check if a product is null

#1 Code example using if/else

```
<li style="line-height:200%">
<b><span style="font-size:16px;">Your products: </span></b>
<ul>
%%[
    IF NOT Empty(@ID_Product_A) THEN 
]%% 
<li><span style="font-size:16px;">%%=v(@ID_Product_A)=%%</span></li>
%%[
    ENDIF
]%%
%%[
    IF NOT Empty(@ID_Product_B) THEN 
]%% 
<li>
    <span style="font-size:16px;">%%=v(@ID_Product_B)=%%</span>
</li>
%%[
    ENDIF
]%% 
%%[
    IF NOT Empty(@ID_Product_C) THEN 
]%% 
<li>
    <span style="font-size:16px;">%%=v(@ID_Product_C)=%%</span>
</li>
%%[
    ENDIF
]%%
```

#2 Code example using inline iif

```
%%=IIf(EMPTY(@ID_Product_A),"", Concat("<li><span style='font-size:16px;'>",@ID_Product_A,"</span></li>"))=%%
%%=IIf(EMPTY(@ID_Product_B),"", Concat("<li><span style='font-size:16px;'>",@ID_Product_B,"</span></li>"))=%%
%%=IIf(EMPTY(@ID_Product_C),"", Concat("<li><span style='font-size:16px;'>",@ID_Product_C,"</span></li>"))=%%
```

Comment: thank you very much, I tried it and it worked ! :)

Comment: @ayakuza91 no worries! please mark the answer accepted so it can help other readers